# Flag OP's comment of question as no longer needed after adding it to the question

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Is it good or make sense to flag a comment of a question from its owner that adds some details to his/her question as *no longer needed* after I added it to the question?

Also I [add a comment about it for OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7128399/4519059)!
But I don't think he will not see it as [his/her profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903257/michael-benson) says *Last seen Sep 2 '11 at 22:39*.

Comment: IMO, given all the other cr*p the moderators have to deal with, I think something like this is too low on the totem pole to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I would use *no longer needed* if I edited the comment into the question. Instead I would use a custom flag to explain that the comment is now edited into the post and can be deleted. The reason for this is to provide enough context in the flag for the mod to act instead of relying on them noticing you just edited the post.

As for your comment:

> I add your comment to the question to make more sense ;)

That is just adding comment noise, basically replacing one with the other. It is superfluous anyway as the OP will get an inbox notification that their post is edited. If you left a descriptive edit comment (not *deleted 8 characters in body; edited title*) the OP will know what happened. And editors are pingable on a post they edited so if they want to complain to you or praise you they can leave a comment and ping you.

*shameless plug of slightly related userscript*

I use a small [usersscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/flag-comments.user.js) to have some canned messages just a mouse click away for various common situations when I do a total comment clean-up under a post (4 or more comments to be removed):

- purge all
  All comments here are either too chatty or obsolete. Please purge them all
- debug session
  All comments here are a back and forth debug session with the outcome captured in the answer. The comments served their goal. Please purge them all.
- resolved in edit
  All comments here are resolved in an edit of the answer. The comments are too chatty or obsolete. Please purge them all.
- debug noise
  All comments here are an one sided debug attempt without resolution and is nothing more then noise. Please purge them all.

[screenshot of the script in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9P17.png)

Comment: Trying to use your userscript using Tampermonkey, but the buttons I assume are supposed to appear when I select "in need of moderator intervention" aren't showing up. Where are they supposed to appear?

Comment: @NathanArthur yes, but only on the Post flag dialog, not on the comment flag one ....

Comment: Ok, I see! Was looking in the comment dialog.

Comment: @NathanArthur sorry for the confusion. I edited the answer a bit to make that clear.